# django models table value not able to see in html

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created a django app which the quizz answers are saved in db with usser name nd given answers by user. What changes I should made in the views.py to render values in html page named as **x.html**

**models.py**

```
class Quizz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    ans1=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    ans2=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    ans3=models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
```

**views.py**

```
def Index(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        password=request.POST['password']
        x=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if x is not None:
            login(request,x)
            return render(request,'x.html')
        else:

            return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request,'index.html')



def test(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        ans1=request.POST['sky']
        ans2=request.POST['cricket']
        ans3=request.POST['river']
        x=Quizz.objects.create(name=name,ans1=ans1,ans2=ans2,ans3=ans3)
        x.save()
        return redirect('test.html')
    return render(request,'test.html')
```

**html template**

```
 {{quizz.ans1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To render values from the model, you need to provide the model data in the `context` parameter to the render function. The `context` parameter is a dictionary that tells Django what to put inside the HTML file. Right now, you're returning `render(request,'x.html')` which renders x.html without context. So, you need to add context to the render function (i.e. what is the quizz). From your code, I am unclear what question you'd like to display in your x.html file.

A simple example would be:

```
question = Quizz.objects.all().first() # Gets the first Quizz object (replace with any other method of obtaining a question)
return render(request, 'x.html', {'quizz': question})
```

Comment: there are quetions in test.html which user answers and those ans are saved in db now all these ans table is want to show into x.html in tabular form

Comment: If you want to show multiple questions in the `x.html`, you need to change the code quite a bit. First, you need to change the context to return a list of questions instead of a single question like in my code snippet. Second, you need to change your `x.html` to loop through the questions using a `for` tag to display your table.